# Config.GetSection<T> with invalid class property names

Tags: c#, .net, config, getter, automatic-properties

Using IConfigurationRoot extension method

```
public static T GetSectionAsObject<T>(this IConfigurationRoot configuration, string key)
{
    return configuration.GetSection(key).Get<T>();
}
```

I am retrieving sections from configuration file as objects.
For example I have a section in configuration file:

```
"RandomClass": {
    "Attribute1": "x",
    "Attribute2": "y",
    "Attribute3": "z"
  },
```

which gets mapped to an object of class RandomClassSettings

```
public class RandomClassSettings
    {
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute3 { get; set; }
    }
```

This works.

Unfortunately, in the configuration file I have another section with a key "attribue.RandomAttribue" which won't get mapped to object like in the previous example because of the "." in it's name. Any ideas how to make it possible? I can't rename the key in configuration file.

I tried making another class Attribute and having a class like below, but it doesn't work either.

```
public class NewClassSettings {
        public Attribute attribute { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit**: I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Just a thought, try `"attribue_RandomAttribue"`. No guarantees, but I've seen similar things n other places.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, doesn't work though :/

Comment: Oh well, just a thought. Sorry, no other ideas right now

Comment: how are you calling `GetSectionAsObject`?

Comment: I got IConfigurationRoot from `ConfigurationBuilder().-some setup-.Build()`. Since I have an extension method then I just call `config.GetSectionAsObject<WantedClass>(configKey)`

Answer (score 4):

Data from `appsettings.json` doesn't get JSON deserialized, a custom [JsonConfigurationFileParser](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs) takes care of the parsing. Any `System.Text.Json` nor `Json.NET` attributes are not being considered.

Here, you'll need to apply a [ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationkeynameattribute) on the property of the class representing that data.

Suppose your data looks like below with that mentioned `attribue.RandomAttribue` key.

```
{
    "data": {
        "attribue.RandomAttribue": "abc"
    }
}
```

Then your class will need to look like this - you can give the property with the `ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute` any name of your choice.

```
public class Data
{
    [ConfigurationKeyName("attribue.RandomAttribue")]
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

You get that data with below call.

```
var data = configuration.GetSection("data").Get<Data>();
Console.WriteLine(data.Item); // abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I'm developing on .NET Framework 4.7.2, not .NET Core.

Comment: @chuftica You'll need to reference [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/7.0.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab) with support for `.NET Framework`.